# Why app is blocked by semaphore?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore, phasset

I have the following function that suppose to return `[CIImage]` for my purpose - displaying some metadata of photos in tableView.

```
func getCIImages() -> [CIImage] {
    var images = [CIImage]()
    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: nil)

    for i in 0..<assets.count {
        guard let asset = assets[i] as? PHAsset else {fatalError("Cannot cast as PHAsset")}  
        let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

        asset.requestContentEditingInputWithOptions(nil) { contentEditingInput, _ in
            //Get full image
            guard let url = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL else {return}
            guard let inputImage = CIImage(contentsOfURL: url) else {return}
            images.append(inputImage)
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    }
    return images
}
```

but it stucks in semaphore wait and didn't go further. I have walked through many tutorials but other variants of GCD don't works. I think it's because of simulator, I don't know, can't test on real device. Please help.

Comment: Why do you force a quasi-synchronous request at all?

Comment: @vadian because i want to display some metadata of `CIImages` in `tableView` and it is can be done by synchronous manner with one `tableView.reloadData()` call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

guards inside `requestContentEditingInputWithOptions` callback closure prevents signal sent to semaphore.
In such cases (when you need cleanup actions) it is good to use [defer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID514). In your case:

```
asset.requestContentEditingInputWithOptions(nil) { contentEditingInput, _ in
    defer { dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore) }

    //Get full image
    guard let url = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL else {return}
    guard let inputImage = CIImage(contentsOfURL: url) else {return}
    images.append(inputImage)
}
```

**UPDATE**

Apart from cleanup bug there is another one. Completion closure of `requestContentEditingInputWithOptions` called on main thread. Which means that if you blocking main thread with semaphore: completion closure is blocked form executing as well. To fix blocked semaphore issue you need call `getCIImages` on a different thread than main.

Anyway making asynchronous things synchronous is wrong. You should think of different approach.

Comment: Exactly the case why `defer` has been introduced!

Comment: None one of the `guard` does not calls `else` statement. This code produces the same behavior like my code - programm freezes

Comment: @Silmaril Even if I make the call asynchronous how I can return the all images?

Comment: @AndreyM. It depends on your requirements. But I created a simple example for you: https://gitlab.com/snippets/24749. Hope this will be enough to understand the idea.